# How to disable Master page in MasterDetailPage of Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am working with `Xamarin` forms and I need to disable the `Master` page that I use as context menu depending on whether user is logged in or not. I have both `Master` and `Detail` pages as separate `XAML` pages.

```
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <view:MenuPage/>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>

  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <view:MainViewPage 
      x:Name="MainView"/>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

As you might have guessed, I am trying to incorporate `MVVM` here, so I tried binding visibility (`IsVisible`) and enabled (`IsEnabled`) properties of the `Master` page, however, I still get the undesired black fade effect when pushing navigation button to access my menu. Instead, I need to completely eat up the button press action.

Answer (score 0):

Should your pages be visible whenever the user is connected or not ?
Or do you have a login page at the start of the application for example ?

If you don't have pages that are visible by both connected users or not, you could implement the login page or another page by defining it as ContentPage. It will take all the screen space and hide the navigationBar.
Then after user connect you call a page as MasterDetailPage and then you will have your navigationBar, ...

Don't know if that's what you're looking for but i hope i was able to help you.

Comment: Sure i can do that.
So first you have your Application class, it will define your MainPage as the page to show right after the launch screen, like that : 

`MainPage = new LoginPage();`

Then your LoginPage need to be a ContentPage and not a MasterDetailPage. With this it's going to be a full screen page without any navigation bar.
If user is logged you redirect to a MasterDetailPage which will have a left side menu.
On that page you will define the Master & the Detail page. The Detail page will be access via a NavigationPage. The Detail page is a simple page with your menu (listview for ex).

Comment: Seems like there no way at the moment to do what I want with MasterDetail page. So as advised, I will use two separate pages for registered and new users. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Don't hesitate if you have problem implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a custom NavigationRenderer, by overriding the Click event of the drawer icon with your custom logic.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace RTW.Mobile.App.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer, IMessageSender
    {
        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as ImageButton;
                var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;

                if (drawerArrow == null)
                    continue;

                //ensure only one handler is registered
                imageButton.Click -= imageButton_Click;
                imageButton.Click += imageButton_Click;
            }
        }

        private void imageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!App.IsBlockingConditionTrue)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<IMessageSender>(this, "ToggleMasterIsPresented");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just subscribe to the message with 
`MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IMessageSender>(this, "ToggleMasterIsPresented", OnToggleMasterIsPresented);` 
and handle it.

```
    private void OnToggleMasterIsPresented(IMessageSender obj)
    {
        _masterDetailPage.IsPresented = !_masterDetailPage.IsPresented;
    }
```